# Angular 2 - Error: No provider for FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-providers, angular-validation

I writing a library for the community, which needs access to the form control and listens on the value changed.

Here's how I did previously when using angular 2.3 and 4.0.

```js
export class ValidationMessageDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('validationMessage') customMessage: string;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private formControl: NgControl, private validationMessageService: ValidationMessageService) {
        this.target = $(el.nativeElement);
        this.formGroup = this.target.closest('.form-group');

        this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue) => {
            this.checkValidation();
        });
    }
}
```

But this code is not working anymore after upgrade to angular 4.1.
Here's the error that I get:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NgControl!`

Any suggestion or idea for me to listen on the value changed in the directive?

**UPDATE 1:**
here's my `index.ts`

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationMessageDirective } from './src/ng2-validation-message.directive';
import { ValidationMessageService } from './src/ng2-validation-message.service';

export * from './src/ng2-validation-message.directive';
export * from './src/ng2-validation-message.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ValidationMessageDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        ValidationMessageDirective
    ],
})
export class Ng2ValidationMessage {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: Ng2ValidationMessage,
            providers: [ValidationMessageService]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your module bootstrap ts?

Comment: @wannadream yeah. just posted my `index.ts`. please have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem happens when the input is not a form control, due to I didn't provide a `name` attribute for the input.
not related to Angular version problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
import { ..., FormControlDirective, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [FormControlDirective, FormGroupDirective]
})
```

Comment: still the same. =(

Comment: I created an issue on Github.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16772
hope someone can help.